# Apache tomcat domain localhost or other :8080 ,how to find that?

Tags: java, tomcat, dns, localhost

In production, at a location, Tomcat is running, port 8081. And when I deploy war at webapps there, I can run the application by visiting URL
**mysweeper.com:8081/myApp**

Now there another tomcat is running at 8080, location at machine is different. There, I want to deploy my war for some reason. It is running also. but when I run localhost:8080 there, it does not work. Is there any 'othername:8080'? How to know that or where to find that?

Comment: That is OS specific. Basically, using OS tools, find which process is listening to 8080 (it will be a java) and check its command line options of the process to find where is the tomcat.

Comment: Also, are you sure it is not the same tomcat? Tomcat can use different ports for different listeners.

Comment: If the port 8080 is used by any other application, your tomcat wont start. It will throw an exception while starting that the port 8080 is in use.

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms, `localhost` is a wobbly to say the best. You could try using `http://127.0.0.1:8080/myApp', or`http://localhost.:8080/myApp`

The second one is sometimes necessary on Windows, when proxy settings mess things up.